# Remove and restore AVPlayer to enable background video playback

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I have a `UIWebView` that plays video. I'd like the video to continue playing when the app goes to the background state. In Apple's [Technical Q&A QA1668](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1668/_index.html), they state:

> If the AVPlayer's current item is displaying video on the device's
>   display, playback of the AVPlayer is automatically paused when the app
>   is sent to the background. There are two ways to prevent this pause:
>
> Disable the video tracks in the player item (file-based content only).
>   See Listing 2. Remove the AVPlayerLayer from its associated AVPlayer
>   (set the AVPlayerLayer player property to nil). See Listing 3.

The following code is what's shown under Listing 3.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface MyPlayerLayerView : UIView
@end

@implementation MyPlayerLayerView

- (AVPlayerLayer *)playerLayer {
  return (AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer];
}

+ (Class)layerClass {
  return [AVPlayerLayer class];
}

@end

@interface MyAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
...
@end

@implementation MyAppDelegate

...

/* Remove the AVPlayerLayer from its associated AVPlayer
    once the app is in the background. */
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
  MyPlayerLayerView *playerView = <#Get your player view#>;
  [[playerView playerLayer] setPlayer:nil]; // remove the player
}

/* Restore the AVPlayer when the app is active again. */
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  MyPlayerLayerView *playerView = <#Get your player view#>;
  [[playerView playerLayer] setPlayer:_player]; // restore the player
}

...

@end
```

I'm trying to convert it to Swift but am confused as to what to do at `<#Get your player view#>;` Can someone clarify what that means and/or how to go about this in Swift?

Comment: so did it work out for you @dperk?

Comment: On background-
{
        playerToRestore = playerLayer?.player
        playerLayer?.player = nil   
}

 On did become active
{
        playerLayer?.player = playerToRestore
 } @chicobermuda

Comment: @pwc please check..hope u will get the help.

Answer (score 0):

In AppDelegate

```
var error: NSError?
var success = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: &error)
if !success {
 NSLog("Failed to set audio session category.  Error: \(error)")
}
```

In MoviePlayerViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
   super.viewDidLoad()  
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "playBgVideo", name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
}
func playBgVideo()
{
  NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: "hello", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
func hello()
{
  movieplayer?.play()
}
```

try this i hope it's works!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you have a `UIViewController` that contains the `UIWebView` that is playing the video. You can register that view controller to receive notifications when the app enters the background and when the app becomes active.

When the app enters the background, you can recursively walk through the view hierarchy to find a view with an `AVPlayerLayer`. If you find one, you can save the player to an instance variable and set the layer's player to nil.

When the app becomes active again, you can recursively walk through the view hierarchy again to find the appropriate view and restore the player.

I used a similar method to enable an `AVPlayerViewController` to continue video playback in the background.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "applicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification:", name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "applicationDidBecomeActiveNotification:", name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
}

var playerViewToRestore: UIView? = nil
var playerToRestore: AVPlayer? = nil

func applicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    guard let view = findPlayerView() else {
        return
    }

    guard let playerLayer = view.layer as? AVPlayerLayer else {
        return
    }

    playerViewToRestore = view
    playerToRestore = playerLayer.player

    playerLayer.player = nil
}

func applicationDidBecomeActiveNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    if playerToRestore == nil {
        return
    }

    guard let playerLayer = playerViewToRestore?.layer as? AVPlayerLayer else {
        return
    }

    playerLayer.player = playerToRestore

    playerViewToRestore = nil
    playerToRestore = nil
}

private func findPlayerView() -> UIView? {
    return findViewWithAVPlayerLayer(self.view)
}

private func findViewWithAVPlayerLayer(view: UIView) -> UIView? {
    if view.layer.isKindOfClass(AVPlayerLayer) {
        return view
    }

    for v in view.subviews {
        if let found = findViewWithAVPlayerLayer(v) {
            return found
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but looping through the views of UIWebView (while a video embedded with YouTube's iFrame is player), only provides CALayers and and UIWebLayer. The views I get are _UIWebViewScrollView, UIWebBrowserView and a couple of UIImageViews. Any clue why I am not able to find an AVPlayerLayer ?? @pwc